# Sharepoint 2010 development on Windows XP 32-bit?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-xp, sharepoint-2010, 32-bit

Possible or not?

I know Sharepoint 2010 Server won't even run on a client side of Vista/Windows 7 64-bit, forget about Windows XP 32-bit.

But if I can install and use Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP just fine, shouldn't Sharepoint development tools also work on Windows XP 32-bit?

The thing is I have a very old laptop (from 2005) that doesn't even support 64-bit architecture so I am stuck with WinXP 32bit.

If there is any way at all of (Remote?) Sharepoint development on Windows XP 32-bit with VS2010 please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of what the developer tools offer you make two assumptions:

- You are running on a 64-bit architecture
- SharePoint is installed side-by-side with Visual Studio

Running on a 32-bit XP machine breaks these assumptions. Many of the built-in Visual Studio productivity aids, such as the deploy and retract commands, will fail. I couldn't even create a project using the SharePoint 2010 project template under similar conditions.

You might make some headway by using regular class library or web application projects, copying SharePoint .dll's from a server's GAC (for use as references) and by manually creating your .ddl and .wsp files using MakeCab (as I did with 2007, with a little help from PowerShell); however, it sounds excruciating compared to running on Vista SP2 X64 or Windows 7 X64 with SharePoint installed.

Comment: You can look to using WSPBuilder or STSDev to help create your WSP

It is also possible to setup remote debugging but this can be more tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had given up on WSPBuilder when, several years ago, I couldn't talk management into allowing me to install SP2007 on my dev workstation. Things may have gotten better since then, I would hope. I've just been out of the WSPBuilder loop.

Comment: After thinking about it your PS scrips sound like a better idea, they are also more portable.

Comment: @JC: Maybe. They were a lot of work. I parse the .csproj file to collect file names of all the various XML, aspx, ascx, webpart, etc. files, generate the .ddl file based on our project organization conventions, and then run makecab. It's a giant, fragile script. It got the job done, and we still use it in our 2007 environment, but it took a couple of weeks to iron out.

Answer (score 3):

As per the above answer, VS 2010 SharePoint projects require a local installation of SharePoint.  You can use external tools for doing your development, such as WSPBuilder, but I do not recommend this approach.  You are best sticking to the MS tools.

Your options are:

1. Upgrade to Windows 7 x64 or Server 2008 R2
2. Run VMWare Server (free) which should enable you to run a 64-bit VM on a 32-bit host (I think? Not sure about this assumption actually), and create a VM with Win7 x64 or Win 2008 R2 for SP development.

Comment: Regarding #2, you are absolutely correct that VMWare can run 64-bit software on a 32-bit host, under conditions that the motherboard supports that kind of emulation. It varies by machine, but can be an option if the hardware supports it. I'll vote +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't recommend 3td party extensions like WSPBuilder.

Comment: @JC: I can't speak for husainnz, but in 2007, I couldn't do half of what WSPBuilder provided because I didn't have SP2007 installed on my dev workstation. I don't know if this is still the case, since my last attempt was nearly three years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Win7 64bit as your dev environment
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

Comment: Please read my post. My CPU does not support 64-bit architecture or I'd gladly install Windows Server 2008 64 on it.